# Getting error while creating table; I am new to SQL

Tags: mysql

```
 EMP_ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT=001, 
FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(25),
LAST_NAME VARCHAR(25),
SALARY INT,
JOINING_DATE DATETIME(0000-00-00 00:00:00),
DEPARTMENT VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY(EMP_ID)
);
```

Comment: Provide COMPLETE code, not a part of it.

Comment: And what error do you get?

Comment: @AmitVerma Where's the comment where the author says they're using "popsql"?

Answer (score 1):

Correct syntax in MySql is

```
Create table employee(
   EMP_ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT , 
   FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(25),
   LAST_NAME VARCHAR(25),
   SALARY INT,
   JOINING_DATE DATETIME ,
   DEPARTMENT VARCHAR(50),
   PRIMARY KEY(EMP_ID)
);
```

Comment: are you using mysql ? I have executed this on mysql. it is working.

Comment: can you tell how to set datetime so that it always give the same time while changing date

Comment: @shashikumar *how to set datetime so that it always give the same time while changing date* Do it in BEFORE INSERT trigger.

Comment: @shashikumar please accept the answer as it has resolved create table issue. For date time, it is separate issue.

Comment: @shashikumar One question per question, this is the rule. It allows you to do research by yourself and find answers for *specific problem*, not the task or even a higher level of abstraction.